# How to use UserPasswordHasher in Symfony command?

Tags: symfony, hash

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): int
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $arg_email = $input->getArgument('email');
        $arg_password = $input->getArgument('password');

        if ($arg_email || $arg_password) {
            $io->note(sprintf('You used the email adress: %s', $arg_email));
            $io->note(sprintf('You used the password: %s', $arg_password));

            $user = New User();
            dd($passwordHasher->hashPassword(
                $user,
                'test'
            ));
            
            $user->setEmail($arg_email);
            $user->setPassword($passwordHasher->hashPassword(
                $user,
                'test'
            ));
            $user->setActive(1);
        
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $io->success('User has been created!');
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

So I'm trying to build a custom command that will get your arg. (email/pass) and hash the password and create a user. Simple enough I thought.. I'm not quite sure whats going wrong because I'm getting weird compilere errors, I've tried multiple solutions provided by the *internet* but it comes all back to some what the same error.

> "type" => 64   "message" => "Declaration of
> App\Command\CreateUserCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface
> $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output,
> App\Command\UserPasswordHasherInterface  $passwordHasher): int must be
> compatible with
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface
> $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output)"
> "file" =>
> "E:\BackYardBBQ\project\src\Command\CreateUserCommand.php"

Some of the things i tried are:

1. putting the  interface inside the __constructor for auto wiring = getting an error that you cant use auto wiring
2. building it inside an controller or the authenticator = not working for the same reason my other failed attempts where.
3. building it inside the constructor of the controller

The error if you try autowiring

> Cannot autowire service "App\Command\CreateUserCommand": argument
> "$entityManager" of method "__construct()" has type
> "App\Command\EntityManagerInterface" but this class was not found.

Comment: You can't inject additional services into the execute method.  That sort of magic only works for a controller action.  Inject the service into the commands construct method and remember to call the parent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable namespaces

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use App\Entity\User;
```

You also need to add `EntityManagerInterface` and `UserPasswordHasherInterface` to your team constructor

```
private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
private UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasherInterface){
    $this->entityManager = $em;
    $this->passwordHasher = $passwordHasherInterface;
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Now you will be able to use them in your command like this:

```
$user->setPassword($this->passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, 'test'));

$this->entityManager->persist($user);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Thankss man this worked fine almost had it right :)

Comment: ``` $this->entityManager->persist($user);$this->entityManager->flush();``` for the next person